# Mustache js output mustache js code

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I'm trying to make Mustache JS output content without parsing some variables. For example:

```
{{block.type}}-{{block.id}}-label-{{element.id}}
```

I want it to just parse the block, and that is why I am giving it the following JSON:

```
{ block: { type: 'news', id: 23 } }
```

The end result should be

```
news-23-label-{{element.id}}
```

but instead it is

```
news-23-label-
```

How should I make it not parse a part of the code? I'm new in Mustache JS and I could not find this in the documentation (comments I understood, if and foreach I understood, but I could not find this).

Answer (score 2):

Would this workaround help you? [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/qK5NT/12/) for fiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="test1">
    {{block.type}}-{{block.id}}-label-{{block.elId}}
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var output = $("#output"),
    template = $("#test1").html(),
    data = '{ "block": { "type": "news", "id": 23, "elId": "{{element.id}}" } }',
    html = Mustache.render(template, JSON.parse(data));

output.append(html);
```

**Output:**

```
news-23-label-{{element.id}}
```

Comment: It's a good workaround, but would be awesome to just have it from the start

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be possible now. You can change and then restore the default delimiter. Example from documentation's `Variables` section you can find here https://github.com/janl/mustache.js (see last three lines of template):

View:

```
{
  "name": "Chris",
  "company": "<b>GitHub</b>"
}
```

Template:

```
* {{name}}
* {{age}}
* {{company}}
* {{{company}}}
* {{&company}}
{{=<% %>=}}
* {{company}}
<%={{ }}=%>
```

Output:

```
* Chris
*
* &lt;b&gt;GitHub&lt;/b&gt;
* <b>GitHub</b>
* <b>GitHub</b>
* {{company}}
```